# Trouble making a Simple video renderer with the python module Pygame

Tags: python, audio, video, pygame

I need some help creating a video renderer in Pygame. It has a 48x36 display and has 3 colours. Black, white and grey. The data that goes into the project is in the form of a .txt file and each frame of the video in a line(as an example my video uses 6567 frames so there are 6567 lines in the text file). To render the frames I am using the rectangle function.

```py
pygame.draw.rect(canvas, rect_color, pygame.Rect(30,30,60,60))
```

(By the way in the .txt file 0=black, 1=white and 2=grey)

After finally making a window pop up it stayed a rather boring black color...

After finally making a window pop up it stayed a rather boring black color...
If you could give any help it would be greatly needed!

(The code is messy i know)

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pygame
file= open(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\video Data.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
current_l = 1
start_time = time.perf_counter()
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))
color = (150,75,75)
def start_vid():
    current_l = 1
    for frame in range(1, 6572):
        xpos = 0
        ypos = 0
        now = datetime.now()
        count = 0
        seconds = now.second
        frame_data = lines[current_l]
        current = frame_data[count]
        for y in range(0, 36):
            for x in range(0, 48):
                if current == '0':
                    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0,   0, 255),[xpos, xpos+10, ypos, ypos+10], 0)
                elif current == '1':
                    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,   255, 255),[xpos, ypos, xpos, ypos], 0)
                else:
                    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (130,   130, 130),[xpos, ypos, xpos, ypos], 0)
                #print(current)
                #pygame.display.update()
                xpos = xpos + 10
                current = frame_data[count]
                count = count + 1
                timer = round(abs((start_time - time.perf_counter())), 1)
                current_l = seconds*30
                current_l = int(timer*30)
            ypos = ypos + -10
        print(current_l)
        
        pygame.display.update()

start_vid()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't see anything is because in Pygame, the origin `(0, 0)` of the screen is in the top left. The right side of the screen is where the `x` increases, and the bottom is where the `y` increases. So, the line:

```
ypos = ypos + -10
```

draws everything "above" the screen, hence invisible. You need to remove the `-` sign.

---

I also saw a couple of things in your code that could be improved, such as:

- The fact that you never close the data file. To do that automatically, you could use the [`with` statement](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/):

```py
with open('video.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
# the file is closed
```

This will allow other applications to access the file.

- You are drawing empty rects

You are using the `pygame.draw.rect` method incorrectly. You should use [rect objects](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) like such:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, rect)
```

- You don't need the `time` and `datetime` modules, Pygame handles time [like this](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html). For example:

```py
framerate = 30
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()

... # main loop
    current_frame = int((pygame.time.get_ticks()-start) / 1000 * framerate)
```

#### And, most importantly

In Pygame, you need a [**main loop** with events handling](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html):

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    ...

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

A correct implementation of your code could look like this:

```py
import pygame

with open('video.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))
framerate = 30
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()

run = True
while run:
    # get pygame events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # user closes the window
            run = False

    current_frame = int((pygame.time.get_ticks()-start) / 1000 * framerate)
    if current_frame < len(lines): # is the video still running?
        count = 0
        for y in range(36):
            for x in range(48):
                current_pixel = lines[current_frame][count] # current pixel data
                if current_pixel == '0':
                    color = (0, 0, 0)
                elif current_pixel == '1':
                    color = (127, 127, 127)
                else:
                    color = (255, 255, 255)
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, pygame.Rect(x*10, y*10, 10, 10))
                count += 1 # next pixel

    pygame.display.flip()

# user closed the window
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

(In this example, you can reduce the amount of resources used since you know the framerate of the video using [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock))